# Symfony2 access to Global Variables from a twig template in console command with translations

Tags: php, symfony, console, twig, translation

i have in my twig template something like this

```
{{ 'movie.title'|trans({'%name%': movie.name},seo) }}
```

where seo is a global variable defined in config.yml, everything work on website correctly but when i want check translations with console command, it doesnt know the variable seo and in output i see this

```
State     Domain       Id                 Message Preview (de)
Missing   _undefined   movie.title        movie.title
```

command

```
debug:translation de InitBundle
```

i need to have domain as a parameter. Can anybody help me, thank you.